# Immediately snap Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My app uses a `RecyclerView` with a `LinearLayoutManager` and a `LinearSnapHelper`.
At the start of my app I want my `RecyclerView` to immediately scroll to a snap position without any animation.

I know of `RecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition()` but that animates the scroll. Any ideas how to achieve this? Thanks! :)

**Code**

Set up the `RecyclerView`:

```
mRecyclerRooms = (RecyclerView) mView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerRooms);
mRoomsLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
mRecyclerRooms.setLayoutManager(mRoomsLayoutManager);
mSnapHelperRooms = new LinearSnapHelper();
mSnapHelperRooms.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerRooms);
mRecyclerRooms.addOnScrollListener(mRoomScrollListener);
```

XML for `RecyclerView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/recyclerRooms"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
  android:clipToPadding="false"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

`mRoomScrollListener()` is used to calculate the distance to snap via `float distanceFromSnap = abs(mSnapHelperRooms.calculateDistanceToFinalSnap(mRecyclerRooms.getLayoutManager(), view)[0]);` and then scale the item accordingly. The idea is to make items get bigger and have more alpha when they are near the snap position which should be the center of the `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
recyclerViewList.scrollToPosition(position);
```

Comment: I tried that, but that does not even scroll near the exact snap position for me. Do you know why?

Comment: I think I found out why its not scrolling properly. I want my items to always snap in the center of the `RecyclerView` and for that I added huge paddings to the RecyclerView in the XML Layout. That seems to break the scrolling. Any idea how to make it always snap to the center of the RecyclerView without breaking the scrolling?

Comment: u want to scroll the recycler view to centre of the items ?

Comment: When I use `smoothScrollToPosition(int item)` or `scrollToPosition(int item)` I want the given item to be in the center of the `RecyclerView`. Even when its the first or the last item of the recycler.

Comment: if u move the first item to center the view above it will show empty

Comment: Thank you very much! I added some code, hope it helps you to get what I want to do. Please let me know if you need any more code snippets :)

Comment: will it be okay if items are shuffled ?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( They should have a specific order.

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/09/android-tip-recyclerview-snapping-with.html?m=1

This might help. But I am worried that Linear snap helper is enough for snapping at center.